# Connecting to a PHP server via Java socket

Tags: java, php, sockets, process

```
try {
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("php", "-S", "localhost:" + port, "-t", path);
    process = processBuilder.start();
    new Logger(process, port);
    System.out.println("Server running on localhost:" + port);
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

At one point I made a connection to a PHP server using a `ProcessBuilder` and `Process`. But once I try to reach the same connection using sockets (in `Logger` class)

```
private Process process;
private Socket connection;

public Logger(Process process, int port)
{
    this.process = process;
    try {
        this.connection = new Socket("127.0.0.1", port);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

I read somewhere else that it might be a firewall problem, but it doesn't look like it is.

How do I connect to an existing PHP server using sockets? Is there a better method to it?

**EDIT:** 
Weirdly enough, when I run `telnet 127.0.0.1 8888` it reports:

> Connecting To 127.0.0.1...Could not open connection to the host, on port 8888: Connect failed

but if I run the server on a browser, it works just fine. I thought that PHP was a socket server itself. Do I need to create a SocketServer in each PHP script/website that I want to track?

**EDIT2:**
But then again, if I run another server, ie. XAMPP it gets caught with `telnet` and I get no errors if I try to do something like:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 80);
```

Comment: have you ensured that the php process is still listening on the given port, for example with the telnet command?

Comment: @RolandBär Can you give an example? I can ensure with .isAlive() that the process is indeed still alive (+ I can still load the PHP in the browser, so the server Is working)

Comment: the command would be `telnet 127.0.0.1 80` but if you can connect via browser the server is working. But maybe it is not yet running when you try to connect. Maybe you can put a sleep for some seconds between starting the server and trying to connect

Comment: @RolandBär Nope, tested. made the thread sleep for even 10 seconds before connection is created, but I still get the same error. Looks like I'll need to take another aproache... (possibly listen to one port for connection (ie. 80) and redirect to the PHP server afterwards (ie. 8080))

Comment: @RolandBär weirdly enough, telnet can't reach it, neither... but the browser registers the server just fine

Comment: Im not sure if you maybe mix some ports when you test the connection. The default port for HTTP is 80, if you want to connect to another port in the browser you have to write it explicit in the address bar like `http://localhost:8888/`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96218/discussion-between-roland-bar-and-nemanjat).